# If $g^2 = e$ for $g$ unique then $hg = gh$

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group. If there is a single element $g \in G$ with $g^2 = e,g \neq e, $ then $hg = gh \,\,\forall h \in G$. We may write $hg = hg^{-1} = (gh^{-1})^{-1}$ but somehow I can not come to the result. I tried different such products. Can you provide a suggestion or a solution ? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the element $hgh^{-1}$. What does its square equal to?

Comment: Very slick. $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 3):

If $g$ is the only element of order 2, then the only subgroup of $G$ of order 2 is $\langle g \rangle = \{ e, g\}$ (why?).

But then $\forall h\in G$, we have that $$h\langle g \rangle h^{-1} = \langle g \rangle.$$
But $heh^{-1}=hh^{-1}=e$, so this forces $hgh^{-1}=g$ (again, why?) which is equivalent to $hg=gh$ as desired.

Comment: It may be helpful to add a line or so explaining why $h\langle g \rangle h^{-1} = \langle g \rangle$ though....